# How to edit the bst files in order to change how author names look?

Tags: bibtex

For example, I am currently using a bst file which gives author name (John Bob Marley) as `J. B. Marley`.

However, I want it to be `Marley, J. B.` instead.
How do I edit the bst file to make it happen?

Thanks in advance.
I want to use this bst file as every other structure of the file matches the journal where I want to submit.

Comment: See the [Tame the BeaST](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast) document.

Comment: The very simple answer is, use a citation style with BibTeX that formats citations as you want (or create it with makebst); or switch to BibLaTeX, where you can format everything yourself to your liking.

Comment: No need to close any more, since Mico's answer answers the general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bibliography style file you employ almost certainly features a function called `format.names`. In this function, look for a substring of the form

```
nameptr "{f. }{vv }{ll}{, jj}" format.name$
```

Change it to

```
nameptr "{vv }{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$
```

This formatting directive informs BibTeX that the abbreviated first names should be placed last.

As you can probably guess, the `vv`, `ll`, `jj` and `f.` particles refer to the von, surname, junior, and (abbreviated) first-name components of a "full" name.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. I had suggested closing, since we haven't heard from the OP since March, but this is a good answer for the general case of how names are formatted.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Many thanks for the compliment. :-) I figured it would be useful to provide a quick tutorial for how BibTeX formats a "full" name.

Comment: @Mico I wish you a merry Christmas and a happy new year! Thank you for all your educational answer of the past year!

Comment: @samcarter - Many thanks for your kind wishes! I wish you and yours a merry Christmas and a Happy New Year as well. May it be a good year for all of us.